# Unknown column sql query (solve)

Tags: mysql

I have table absen with clause join, where and group
and I have this query

```
SELECT count( tgl ) AS total, 
       absen.id, pegawai.nama, pegawai.bagian, 
       pegawai.bagian, pegawai.tglmasuk, gaji.jenis_gaji, 
       gaji.jumlah, gajiharian.id_gajiharian, 
       gajiharian.status, gajiharian.tgldigaji,
    CASE WHEN (weekday( tgl ) <=3)
         THEN date( tgl + INTERVAL( 3 - weekday( tgl ) ) DAY )
         ELSE date( tgl + INTERVAL( 3 +7 - weekday( tgl ) ) DAY )
    END AS tglitung
FROM absen
   JOIN pegawai ON pegawai.id = absen.id
   JOIN gaji ON gaji.id = pegawai.id
   LEFT JOIN gajiharian ON gajiharian.id = absen.id
WHERE absen.status = 'm'
  AND absen.id = '15'
  AND tglitung='2016-01-14'
GROUP BY absen.id, tglitung
```

and results in

> #1054 - Unknown column 'tglitung' in 'where clause'

How do I solve that?
I want 'as tglitung' can detect as column.

Comment: Append a table name onto the front of it.

Comment: solve I use having clause

Comment: write it up please (self-answer) so we can wrap this up. Thanks.

Comment: MySQL apparently allows that expression in the `having` clause but you are still referring to a non-aggregated `tgl` when you do so. Be careful with that.